# i'm working in office and my office chair is damage. and i ask to my manger but he always ignore me. what to do

Tags: professionalism

I am working in an office. The office chair is damaged. I complained to my manager already but he ignored me deliberately. Every time I request to him to provide a new chair, he promises me today or tomorrow and so far 2 months have gone by but still has not replaced the chair. What should I do? Should I send an email to headoffice about chair? What should I write in that email?

Comment: You could swap your chair for his and see if he notices then...might not go over so well, but I doubt he would ignore you then.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a totally reasonable question to me (although likely a duplicate)

Comment: The so-called "duplicate question" is not even remotely similar. He's not asking for brand new top of the line equipment, which was not even needed, which is what the other guy was asking for. He's asking for fixing an already broken chair, that has already been broken for the past two months.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd email the boss before I'd contact HQ.

Written requests usually get taken more seriously (since by implication, they can be forwarded to management by the original sender if they're not acted upon).

> Dear Mr. XX,
>
> As you know, my chair is broken. It has been broken since date Y. You've said I would get replacement chair the following week on date Y, date X, date W, and finally on date Z.
>
> This broken chair is an occupational health and safety issue. Please order a replacement office chair for me.

Also, it may help if you've already done some of the research in the catalog yourself, to help expedite the ordering.

> Below is a link to the exact chair that we usually order from our approved vendor ABC.
>
> It's listed at $XX
>
> Thank you,
>
> John YY
>
> PS: Attached is a picture of the currently broken chair in question.

That being said, if you believe that your relationship with your boss has already deteriorated to such a point, that he might fire you for sending such a message to him, then you might want to consider using a different strategy altogether.

Also, if the chair doesn't look broken from the picture alone, then don't send it. Only attach that picture if it obviously looks broken. This is not for your boss's benefit. This is in case that message needs to be forwarded to HR, or up the chain of command.

Comment: I'd maybe drop the paragraph about "having done anything to upset the boss" and add a statement that the broken chair is an occupational health and safety issue.

Comment: @HorusKol, Good call.